# How can I listen to document.hasFocus() without using an interval?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, setinterval, event-listener

I want to check if the user changed the view of the current tab, that's why I am testing with `if` condition on `document.hasFocus()` and if it's equal to False, then I send an Axios (ajax) request to the backend.

Right now I am using `document.hasFocus()` with `setInterval()` function!
In my case and using the `setInterval` function, the function `checkFocus` got triggered every 2 Seconds and checks if the user `hasFocus`.

The result of this is => if the user changes the tab.. => every 2 seconds an ajax request is sent .. (because of the `setInterval`)
While I want the event to be triggered only 1 time. I want to send only 1 ajax request Each time the user loses the focus..

That's why I can"t use the `SetInterval` Function.
My question is: How can I Listen to `document.hasFocus` without using `SetInterval` Function?

Here is my code:

```
setInterval( checkFocus, 200 );

function checkFocus() {

    if ( document.hasFocus() == false ) {
            axios.post(url).then(function(response){
            }).catch(function(error)  {
                window.alert("Ouch an unexpected error has occurred. Reload the page and try again");
            });
    } 
}
```

Comment: set a flag after posting. check the flag before posting. if the flag is true, don't post. clear the flag when `document.hasFocus()` is true.

Comment: You are triggerring this function every 200 milliseconds not 2 seconds setInterval( checkFocus, 200 ); if you want to trigger every 2 sends then use 2000 in the setInterval parameter.